# Get results from shell and export to Excel

Tags: powershell

Running the following command to run a sql script

```
$InvokeParams = @{
 Server = 'test'
 Database = 'test2'
 Username = 'admin'
 Password = 'password'
 InputFile = 'business.sql'
}
Invoke-SqlCmd @InvokeParams

Get-Process | Export-CSV  C:\test1.csv –Show
Invoke-Item C:\test1.csv
```

Once the script is done,  for example :

```
TodayDate : 6/24/2019 12:00:00 AM
PrevDate : 6/23/2019 12:00:00 AM
Count : 100,000

TodayDate : 6/24/2019 12:00:00 AM
PrevDate : 6/23/2019 12:00:00 AM
Count : 200,000
```

shell grabs the output and send the data to test1.csv . TodayDate/PrevDate and Count should be set as columns on test1.csv file

Csv file does not show the output from shellscript - showing all the activities happening at the desktop

The same script will run for different databases

Comment: `Export-Excel` is not some default cmdlet.  Do you have whatever module you expect it to come from installed?  Are you thinking `Export-Csv`?

Comment: It creates excel file but excel cannot open the file, format or file extesion is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're capturing the currently running processes in your csv.  If you want the return of your sql command captured, you need to either pipe from it, or capture it in a variable:

```
<# ... #>
$out = Invoke-SqlCmd @InvokeParams

$path = 'C:\test1.csv'
$out | Export-Csv -Path $path
Invoke-Item -Path $path
```

Comment: i would substitute:   out = Invoke-SqlCommand   with out = Invoke-SqlCmd . So right now, i do see table results , but how could I run the same script with a different database, results will be exported to the same file , all the outputs will be listed in 1 single table

Comment: @user9191 Are the table schema the same?  You can use the `-Append` switch on `Export-Csv`.  If they're not, you need different files or to learn the `ImportExcel` module.

Comment: all databases export the same table schema, ( same headers/ set up) with a different values

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to download/install the module first according to the [documentation](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.0), which means:

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 5.4.0
```